# What is the meaning of non-reduced structure of null-cone for a finite group action. (Related to derived equivalence?)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, derived-categories

Suppose $G$ is a finite group acting on a finite dimensional vector space $W$. The null cone is the vanishing of the ideal of the $G$-invariant polynomials that vanish at $0$. Symbolically - $I = \{ f \in S^k(V^) : f(0) = 0, gf = f\}$, and $N = V(I)$.

The structure sheaf of the null cone is supported at the origin.

This subscheme doesn't have to be reduced. For example, if $C_2$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by $-1 \to -I$ then the nullcone is the vanishing of $(x^2,xy,y^2)$. If it acts by $\rho(-1)x_1 = -x_1$, $\rho(-1)x_2 = x_2$, then the nullcone is $V(x_1^2,x_2)$.

Is there any interesting interpretation of this scheme, or its structure sheaf, relating it to the representation of $G$?

For instance, does it determine the representation? Fancily put ... maybe the map from $Rep(G)$ to the Hilbert scheme of points is injective? (Weirdly, this seems to give a natural scheme structure to $Rep(G)$ (each point in $Rep(G)$ gets the structure sheaf of its nullcone). Most groups I know have discrete families of representations, though.)

I am vaguely aware that there is some equivalence of (derived?) categories between coherent sheaves supported at the origin and $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves. Or maybe $G$-equivariant local systems?  Or something like that (hazy memory of someone saying something I didn't understand). Is it related?